# Fiware Cosmos OAuth2 Token Time Increase

Tags: time, token, fiware, fiware-cosmos

**How can I increase the expire time of Authentication Token?** 
I am using given API for Generating an Authentication Token for Cosmos.

> curl -k -X POST
>   "https://computing.dit.upm.es:13000/cosmos-auth/v1/token" -H
>   "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d
>   "grant_type=password&username=&password="

Using this I am getting token only for **3600 seconds** but I want for more time around **24 hours**. 
Please Help Me......

Answer (score 0):

The expiration time of a token is defined inside of the Identity manager that you use, in this case as you are using the Cosmos platform (for testing purposes), the token expiration time is not able to be modified. If you want to define a different expiration time for your token, you need to use your own instance, if you need to do that, the last release of FIWARE IdM allows configuring that parameter.

Comment: how can I set up my own Cosmos instance? Also, where can I setup it?

Comment: Hi Umang, Some information about how to deploy your own Cosmos instance in provided in this link https://github.com/ging/fiware-cosmos/blob/master/doc/manuals/installation_and_administration_manual/some_words_about_cosmos_and_ecosystem.md